# UNET with CrossEntropy Loss Function

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, image-segmentation, cross-entropy

I was trying to train UNET with input size as [3,128,128] and the corresponding mask is [1,128,128] which contains classes directly(instead of pixels it will contain class numbers - 1,2). I am trying for a two-class problem hence my mask contains 1,2 as labels. Now I send my images to the model and the dimension of the predicted masks are [2,128,128]. Now to train a model I choose 16 as batch size. So, now I have input as [16,3,128,128] so the predicted dimension is [16,2,128,128]. But I have ground-truth masks as [16,1,128,128]. Now how can I apply Cross entropy loss in Pytorch? I have tried as follows and getting the following error. Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

```
lr = 0.1  # 0.1
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() #nn.L1Loss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, weight_decay=0.0001)
is_train = True
is_pretrain = False
acc_best = 0
total_epoch = 30
if is_train is True:
    # Training
    for epoch in range(total_epoch):
        model.train()
        tims = time.time()
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            images = Variable(images.permute(0,3,1,2).float().cuda())                                                                                                   
            labels = Variable(labels.type(torch.LongTensor).cuda())
            # Forward + Backward + Optimize
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(images)
            outputs = outputs.type(torch.float)
            print('predictedLabelsType:',outputs[0].type())
            print('ActualLabelsType:',labels[0].type())
            print('shape of predicted outputs:',outputs.shape)
            print('shape of groundtruth masks:',labels.shape)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
```

My output is as follows:

```
predictedLabelsType: torch.cuda.FloatTensor
ActualLabelsType: torch.cuda.LongTensor
shape of predicted outputs: torch.Size([16, 2, 128, 128])
shape of groundtruth masks: torch.Size([16, 1, 128, 128])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b692a8d536a9> in <module>()
     52             print('shape of predicted outputs:',outputs.shape)
     53             print('shape of groundtruth masks:',labels.shape)
---> 54             loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     55             loss.backward()
     56             optimizer.step()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2385         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2386     elif dim == 4:
-> 2387         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2388     else:
   2389         # dim == 3 or dim > 4

RuntimeError: 1only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [16, 1, 128, 128]
```

Could you please suggest where is the mistake and how this CrossEntropyLoss() will work in Pytorch for image segmentation? What I am missing here? I have tried reshaping the target size as [16,128,128] which is leads to another error. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) specifies that if the input is shape `(N, C, d1, d2)` then the target must be shape `(N, d1, d2)`. Instead, your targets are shape `(N, 1, d1, d2)` so you need to remove the unnecessary unitary dimension.

```py
loss = criterion(output, labels.squeeze(1))
```

If you're getting another error from this change then there's another issue with your code, but this is the correct tensor shape for `CrossEntropyLoss`.